# How do I obtain new weapons?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm *new* to CSGO and I can't really figure out lots of things. How can I obtain new weapons? In particular: How do I get the Desert Eagle?

Comment: Why the Desert Eagle in particular? I wouldn't recommend it to new players, it's probably the hardest gun in the game to use properly

Comment: Please mark the answer below as it correctly answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

On a normal match, pressing <kbd>B</kbd> opens up the Buy Menu which allows you to purchase guns, including the deagle.

Answer (score 0):

you can buy one on respawn. Place where you start game just click buy button if you have standard settings you can use "B" key to open buy menu.

Answer (score 0):

once you spawn in or a round ends (depending on game mode) you can buy new weapons, with the B key.

be aware your keybindings may not be the same, and that in some game modes (arms race or demolition) you  will be given guns based on your performance - not your choice.

Some custom servers will also restrict buying options, but if youre in a valve Deathmatch, Casual or Competitive game, upon respawning you can buy weapons. In deathmatch you have infinite cash too.